# Symfony form: how to process a field after valid submission?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have made a Symfony 2 form to edit a `EmailAccount` entity

```
class EmailAccount
{
    protected $host;
    protected $user;
    protected $password;
}
```

**However the `$password` field is encrypted with AES in database.**

So when the user posts `my-secret-password` in the form, I want to set a different value in the entity (the encrypted value).

To encrypt, I have a simple service that does this: `$encrypter->encrypt($string);`

So how can I do this?

Here is my current form type:

```
class EmailAccountType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('host', 'text');
        $builder->add('user', 'text');
        $builder->add('password', 'password');
        $builder->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => EmailAccount::class,
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'emailAccount';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values from form in controller by calling getData():

```
    $form->bind($request); //after this 

    $data = $form->getData(); //all fields array
    $username = $form->get('username')->getData(); // only username field value
    $username = $form->get('username')->getViewData();//before mapping/traansformation
```

So you can encrypt password after checking that form is valid:

```
$form->bind($request);

if ($form->isValid()
{
    $newPassword = $encrypter->encrypt($form->get('password')->getData());
    $user->setPassword($newPassword);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was an option on the field I could set with a callback that would process the field value automatically. But that solution is good enough :)

Comment: There is a method for that. You can use [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to modify form data before saving and thats the 'elegant' way to do what you want.

Comment: Ah that was exactly what I was thinking about, great! I'll have a look into that